# Problems with Getting Response on the deployed bot;

Tags: c#, json, rest, api, botframework

I've got some problems with getting REST API response that allows to get members of the group( GET {serviceUrl}/v3/conversations/{conversationId}/members). I'm debugging my bot in Bot Emulator, and it runs fine here

[image]
 - that's what it shows in the Bot Simulator

[image]
 - But that's how it shows on Azure.

The main problem is that i really can't recognize the problem.I know that the problem is in requesting because the getResponse method crash all programm when it is on server(but why this works in the bot emulator?).Here is the code(I'm using .NET CORE, Microsoft Bot Framework). **P.S.{id} in Authorization is correct, and i get it from another request(but unlike the problem request that request works everywhere), the {url} is turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl**

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest23 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create($"{url}/v3/conversations/{turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id}/members");

await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"{url}/v3/conversations/{turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id}/members");

await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id);

webRequest23.ContentType = "application/json";
webRequest23.Headers["Authorization"] = $"Bearer {id}";
WebResponse response2 = webRequest23.GetResponse();//crash here
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("3");

string smth25 = "";
using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream(), true))
{
        smth25 = stream.ReadToEnd();
}
JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(smth25);
List<string> names = new List<string>();
foreach(var x in jsonArray)
{
         var name = JObject.Parse(x.ToString())["name"].ToString();
         names.Add("@" + name);
}
         string s = "This group consists of - ";
         foreach (var x in names){

         s += "" + x + ",";
}
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(s);
```

Here is how i get id:

```
string stringData = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=66b16ef5-d086-40b7-ae9c-2f50a1f028c6&client_secret=yRUYg4g.:ANuw3Y_01V=@.JkAv=@g3EE&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.botframework.com%2F.default";
var data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(stringData);
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token");
webRequest.Host = "login.microsoftonline.com";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.Method = "POST";
var newStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
newStream.Close();
WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
string line = string.Empty;

string smone = "";
using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), true))
{
    smone = stream.ReadToEnd();
}
var id = JObject.Parse(smone)["access_token"].ToString();
```

Comment: @dbc that's a problem of question, not code.I don't think that problem is in parsing, cause it works in emulator))).Can you help me please?Cause i am really upset and i don't know what to do...

Comment: Is Hilton's answer acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly what your "turnContext.SendActivityAsync" lines are supposed to do, but it might be working in the bot emulator because the emulator doesn't require a proper authenticated session like Teams does. Anyway, something like this should actually help you:

First, define this class somewhere:

```
public class MicrosoftTeamUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string ObjectId { get; set; }

    public string GivenName { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string UserPrincipalName { get; set; }

    public string TenantId { get; set; }
}
```

then use:

```
List<ChannelAccount> teamMembers = (await turnContext.TurnState.Get<IConnectorClient>().Conversations.GetConversationMembersAsync(
                turnContext.Activity.GetChannelData<TeamsChannelData>().Team.Id).ConfigureAwait(false)).ToList();

            List<MicrosoftTeamUser> teamsUsers = new List<MicrosoftTeamUser>();
            foreach (var item in teamMembers)
            {
                var teamsUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MicrosoftTeamUser>(item.Properties.ToString());
                teamsUser.Id = item.Id;
                teamsUsers.Add(teamsUser);
            }
```

Then you'll have the list of members in the teamMembers variable

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i specifically need to connect to the api(or i don't know, does there any ways to delete or add people to the conversation using microsoft teams?

Comment: @МаксШульдинер - `Conversations.GetConversationMembersAsync` *does* connect to the API. Are you saying you actually want to add/delete conversation members rather than just get the conversation members? If so, then you need to accept this answer and ask a new question because that wasn't the question you asked.

Comment: @Kyle Delaney this works very well with emulator and azure, but i don't understand why it doesn't work on telegram for example....

Comment: @Hilton Giesenow Can you help me with my question above?

Comment: @МаксШульдинер - What are you trying to do on Telegram? Are you just trying to use `Conversations.GetConversationMembersAsync` or are you trying to add/delete conversation members? And why are you talking about Telegram when you said you were using Teams? Conversation operations are naturally channel-specific. For example, would you expect Update Activity to work for a chat service that doesn't support message updates? You will only be able to get help with your issues if you're honest about what you're doing. Again, please accept this answer and ask a new question with the correct details.

Comment: I think maybe I'm understanding your challenge - I think you're expecting the "v3/conversations" endpoint to behave like a "regular" REST endpoint, and to honour POST, PATCH, DELETE, etc. Have a look at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), especially the "Conversation operations" section, and you'll see it only supports specific actions. To do things like edit/delete members you'd need to use the Graph API.

Comment: (My comment was too long above).  Here's an example to delete members using Graph - Here's an example to delete members: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-delete-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: @Hilton Giesenow i did that program after reading documentation then you sent to me.I am using GET /v3/conversations/{conversationId}/members api request(it's on the site, you can check my code and it's here).That's bot request to get all members of the conversation.

Comment: @Hilton Giesenow as documentation i mean https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Comment: oh, I see that there is actually a "Delete Conversation Member" method, I hadn't noticed that before. There's no ability to add members this way though. For Teams, you'd need to use Graph API to do that, to add them to the Channel. For Telegram I can't help. At this point it's a very long conversation - I think we've answered the original question, and we've seen how to get the members, possibly even to delete. If there's more you need, I also suggest, as Kyle did, that you add another, more specific question

Comment: @Hilton Giesenow the original question was not about the teams but about bot framework rest api from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0 and azure problems.Please, check my code and see that it's using microsoft bot framework documentation to do my rest api request.

Comment: oh yes, my mistake. The point is, you can't do all the operations you want (add/edit/delete members) using just this endpoint, it's not built for that

Comment: @Hilton Giesenow but what should i do if i want to get/add/edit/delete members for telegram for example?

Comment: @МаксШульдинер - I told you that conversation operations are channel-specific. If you're asking about conversation operations then you are necessarily asking about a specific channel, like Teams or Telegram. So you can't just say "for example" because the answer will be different for each channel and so you need to make sure you say what channel you're using. Do you understand?

Comment: @Kyle Delaney so do you know what should i do with telegram?or no

Comment: @МаксШульдинер - I will be able to tell you if you accept this answer and ask a new question with all the necessary details